# Ubuntu server network autoconfigure failed

Tags: server, ssh, dhcp

I'm novoice Ubuntu server user.

Im using Virtualbox to install Ubuntu Server 13.10

While installation process i got message

```
Network Auto Configuration failed
```

I selected Continue

Now my server installation in completed but not able to connect to it from SSH

[image]

```
IFCONFIG
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a host-only network.

1. Stop your VM
2. Go to VirtualBox Manager
3. Go to `File` > `Preferences...`
4. Click on `Network`
5. Click on `Host-only networks`
6. Click on `Add host-only network` (the + icon on the right)
7. Click on `OK`
8. Go to VirtualBox Manager
9. Select your VM
10. Click on `Settings`
11. Click on `Network`
12. At `Attached to` select `Host-only adapter`
13. At `Name` select your host-only adapter
14. Click `OK`
15. Start your VM

Now log in and execute `ifconfig eth0`. You can access your VM from your host using the IP address displayed after `inet addr`.

Comment: In my Virtualbox Network setting i have 2 lists at Name: "Dell Wireless 1705 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHZ)" and another one "Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller". I check with both but dint see any difference. Also how do i check if my network configuration is working?

Comment: If you're currently using wireless, select `Dell Wireless 1705 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHZ)`. If you're using a wire, select `Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller`. You can check if it's working by executing `ping -c4 8.8.8.8`, if you don't get any timeouts it's working.

Comment: Im using wireless internet connection. so i selected "Dell Wireless 1705 802.11b/g/n (2.4GHZ)". After restart if i give the command "ping -c4 8.8.8.8" i get "Network is unreachable"

Comment: Could you try executing `sudo dhclient eth0`? Do you have a DHCP server in your network (see the note in my answer)? Also, could you please post the output of `ifconfig eth0`?

Comment: i dont see any output for above command. and i am using reliance netconnect wireless i don't know if it has inbuilt DHCP server

Comment: I don't know what that is, sorry. It looks like a USB modem, is this right? In this case bridging won't work because you're not using your WiFi or cable adapter in your notebook. You can use `Host-only networking`. [More info](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html).

Comment: yes its a usb internet connection

Comment: I updated my answer. This should work for you. I have tried this on my Ubuntu host, so it may be a bit different on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is not finding a network adapter.

Verify that your virtual machine has an adapter enabled.

http://www.dedoimedo.com/images/computers_new_1/virtualbox-network-nat-new.png